# SonarQube updating Active Directory users - sonar.security.updateUserAttributes

Tags: active-directory, sonarqube

In our **SonarQube 5.4** we authenticate in **Active Directory** using LDAP plugin and specifying just one property in sonar.properties:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
```

(according to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Microsoft+Active+Directory)

It's a shame they removed the feature to disable updating user properties on every login:

```
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes = false
```

See this:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7219

We've been using it, as update on every login removes assignment of users to **SonarQube built-in groups**, e.g. **sonar-administrators**.

I can give individual users whatever rights in Administration > Security > Global Permissions, but I'd prefer to do this for SonarQube groups, as we have lots of users.

Reflecting the whole setup of groups in AD is difficult, as our Infrastructure teams are too slow and bureaucratic

Is there any other way to achieve what we want?

**UPDATE**

I've tried configuring empty values for group properties:

```
ldap.group.baseDn=
ldap.group.request=
ldap.group.idAttribute=
```

But it doesn't help - every login group membership is resynchronized again from AD and membership in internal SQ groups is removed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable group synchronisation from LDAP, you can simply remove properties ldap.group.*.

See "Group Mapping" http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin.

[link to post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/ldap$20ad$20group/sonarqube/5qToZLeF2vc/MufPBAt1CAAJ)

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned - we use AD specifically and so based on documentation we define only 1 property: sonar.security.realm=LDAP, as all other configurations are automatically detected by the plugin. I've tried setting ldap.group*= empty string, but it didn't help - groups are still synced from AD and membership in internal SQ groups is removed. I've updated the question with this info. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you set al three ldap.group Params by name to empty string it sounds like a bug. Maybe follow up on the thread I linked above? I have in before that suggestion and used ad groups:-/

Comment: Mike, thanks! Do you use it as LDAP (with LDAP server specification) or as in automatic mode for AD?

Comment: I use it in ad mode, but like I said, I gave in and just mapped to ad groups and don't use the internal sonar groups anymore.